# Fabricjs trouble getting radio button to set fabric object change

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm having trouble getting my radio button to change the object added to the fabric canvas on click. Each time the radio button is changed the new icon color remains the green, where it should have changed to the selected color.

The behavior that I'm looking for is when you select the green, yellow, or red radio button the next icon placed on the canvas should become that selected color.

Any ideas?

```js
function iconSet() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  if (document.getElementById("green").checked == true) {
    var iconGreen = new fabric.Triangle({
      width: 62.5,
      height: 50,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      fill: 'green'
    });

    canvas.add(iconGreen);

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
      iconGreen.top = obj.e.y - 30;
      iconGreen.left = obj.e.x - 10;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })
    canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
      iconGreen.top = -100;
      iconGreen.left = -100;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })
    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
      canvas.add(iconGreen.clone());
      canvas.renderAll();
    })
  } else if (document.getElementById("yellow").checked == true) {
    var iconYellow = new fabric.Triangle({
      width: 62.5,
      height: 50,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      fill: 'yellow'
    });

    canvas.add(iconYellow);

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
      iconYellow.top = obj.e.y - 30;
      iconYellow.left = obj.e.x - 10;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
      iconYellow.top = -100;
      iconYellow.left = -100;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
      canvas.add(iconYellow.clone());
      canvas.renderAll();
    })
  } else if (document.getElementById("red").checked == true) {
    var iconRed = new fabric.Triangle({
      width: 62.5,
      height: 50,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      fill: 'red'
    });

    canvas.add(iconRed);

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
      iconRed.top = obj.e.y - 30;
      iconRed.left = obj.e.x - 10;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
      iconRed.top = -100;
      iconRed.left = -100;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
      canvas.add(iconRed.clone());
      canvas.renderAll();
    })
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>


Green<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="green" onclick="iconSet()" /> Yellow

<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="yellow" onclick="iconSet()" /> Red

<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="red" onclick="iconSet()" />

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Declare canvas and obejct variable globally and change fill property of object and trigger method of canvas on change of radio button

```
icon.setFill("yellow");
canvas.renderAll();  
canvas.trigger('object:modified', {target: icon});
```

---

**Example**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var iconTriangle = new fabric.Triangle({
    width: 62.5,
    height: 50,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    fill:"green"
});
canvas.add(iconTriangle);

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
    iconTriangle.top = obj.e.y - 30;
    iconTriangle.left = obj.e.x - 10;
    canvas.renderAll()
});
canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
    iconTriangle.top = -100;
    iconTriangle.left = -100;
    canvas.renderAll()
});
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
    canvas.add(iconTriangle.clone());
    canvas.renderAll();
});

function iconSet() {
    if (document.getElementById("green").checked == true) {
        iconTriangle.setFill("green");
        canvas.renderAll();
    } 
    else if (document.getElementById("yellow").checked == true) {
        iconTriangle.setFill("yellow");
        canvas.renderAll();
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("red").checked == true) {
        iconTriangle.setFill("red");
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

Green<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="green" onclick="iconSet()" /> Yellow
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="yellow" onclick="iconSet()" /> Red
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="red" onclick="iconSet()" />
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: This answer was the best solution for me. However, the mouse:up event triggers an icon to be placed even when moving an existing icon. I'm able to turn off the `mouse:up` event using the below, but can't turn the event listener back on.
`canvas.on('mouse:over', function (obj) {
    canvas.off('mouse:up');
});`
&
`canvas.on('mouse:out', function (obj) {
    canvas.on('mouse:up');
});`

Comment: I'm scratching my head about your snippet triggering `object:modified` event manually after setting `fill`. What's the point?

Comment: In Short. that notifies Canvas that something is modified in object contains in canvas. and it tells canvas that what changes have been made.

Comment: It doesn't really notify Canvas about anything meaningful. It just fires event listeners attached to `object:modified` event. There are no listeners attached to this event by Fabric.js by default, internally. You can check that by calling `console.log(canvas.__eventListeners['object:modified'])`.

Comment: yes. you are right. its even without it. misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating every time [new fabric.Triangle](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Triangle.html) instead of that you can create once and when radio button values changed, just will update color of existing `fabricTriangle` by using [`fabricTriangle.setFill()`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Triangle.html#fill) method.

**See below code snippet**

```js
document.getElementById('green').checked = true;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'),
  fabricTriangle = getfabricTriangle('green');

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
  fabricTriangle.top = obj.e.y - 30;
  fabricTriangle.left = obj.e.x - 10;
  canvas.renderAll()
});

canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
  fabricTriangle.top = -100;
  fabricTriangle.left = -100;
  canvas.renderAll()
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
  canvas.add(fabricTriangle.clone());
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.add(fabricTriangle)

function getfabricTriangle(color) {
  if (!fabricTriangle) {
  //If it is not created then first will create and return..
     return new fabric.Triangle({
      width: 62.5,
      height: 50,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      fill: color
    });
  } /*else {
  //just changing the color of exiting fabric.Triangle...
    fabricTriangle.setFill(color)
  }*/
}

function iconSet() {
  fabricTriangle.setFill(document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value)
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>


Green
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="green" onclick="iconSet()" value="green" /> 

Yellow
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="yellow" onclick="iconSet()" value="yellow" /> 

Red
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="red" onclick="iconSet()" value="red" />

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create `canvas` and the icons to add to it inside a `function` and afterwards you lose track of them. It's not a problem to define a variable inside the function, but you need to have a guarantee to be able to refer to it later. `var` variables are `function`-scoped, which means that you will not be able to reach those variables from outside the `function` call, even if you call the `function` again. Also, you recreate these objects, yet, instead of that, you would need to ensure that you are able to keep track of the variables that you intend to use and to not recreate your canvas object. A quick fix is here:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var icons = {
    green: null,
    yellow: null,
    red: null
};
function iconSet() {
  for (var ic in icons)
    if (icons[ic]) {
      canvas.remove(icons[ic]);
      icons[ic] = null;
    }
  if (document.getElementById("green").checked == true) {
    var iconGreen = new fabric.Triangle({
      width: 62.5,
      height: 50,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      fill: 'green'
    });

    canvas.add(icons.green = iconGreen);

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
      iconGreen.top = obj.e.y - 30;
      iconGreen.left = obj.e.x - 10;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })
    canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
      iconGreen.top = -100;
      iconGreen.left = -100;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })
    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
      canvas.add(iconGreen.clone());
      canvas.renderAll();
    })
  } else if (document.getElementById("yellow").checked == true) {
    var iconYellow = new fabric.Triangle({
      width: 62.5,
      height: 50,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      fill: 'yellow'
    });

    canvas.add(icons.yellow = iconYellow);

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
      iconYellow.top = obj.e.y - 30;
      iconYellow.left = obj.e.x - 10;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
      iconYellow.top = -100;
      iconYellow.left = -100;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
      canvas.add(iconYellow.clone());
      canvas.renderAll();
    })
  } else if (document.getElementById("red").checked == true) {
    var iconRed = new fabric.Triangle({
      width: 62.5,
      height: 50,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      fill: 'red'
    });

    canvas.add(icons.red = iconRed);

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
      iconRed.top = obj.e.y - 30;
      iconRed.left = obj.e.x - 10;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
      iconRed.top = -100;
      iconRed.left = -100;
      canvas.renderAll()
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
      canvas.add(iconRed.clone());
      canvas.renderAll();
    })
  }
}
```

along the ideas I have explained, see the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2yL3qox/). You might want to refactor this further, but this is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need. I have also cleaned up the code make it shorter JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96nceasu/3/

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
function iconSet(ele){
      var icon = new fabric.Triangle({
          width: 62.5,
          height: 50,
          originX: 'center',
          originY: 'center',
          fill: ele.id
        });
        canvas.add(icon);
        canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
          icon.fill = ele.id;
          icon.top = obj.e.y - 30;
          icon.left = obj.e.x - 10;
          canvas.renderAll()
        })
        canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
          icon.top = -100;
          icon.left = -100;
          canvas.renderAll()
        })
        canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
          canvas.add(icon.clone());
          canvas.renderAll();
        })
      
    }
```

```css
canvas{
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>
    Green<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="green" onclick="iconSet(this)" /> Yellow
    <input name="iconType" type="radio" id="yellow" onclick="iconSet(this)" /> Red
    <input name="iconType" type="radio" id="red" onclick="iconSet(this)" />
    <canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```